# how can i merge some maps?

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, hector-slam, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to know, how can i merge two or three maps to one file, maps are created using hector slam?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133486/how-can-i-merge-some-maps?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) on 2014-02-26**:
What do you mean by "merge"?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-26**:
Are they already aligned correctly given the origins in the yaml?

**Comment by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) on 2014-02-26**:
What you can do is load the three maps using the map server. And then subscribe to the 3 of them and consider one as your reference-map. Then, compute the rotations necessary (to align obstacles for example) and then merge the 2 other maps with the reference. Of course you have to pay attention to the sizes and origins of the maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[MapStitch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch) allows merging two previously non-aligned maps, provided they have sufficient overlap, are consistent and have similar appearance for the overlapping areas. We haven´t been using it a lot recently, but it worked in experiments we did a few months ago. You might also want to check out the "robocup" branch, as this contains potentially useful bugfixes. Unfortunately, I´m not able to look after it myself currently.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2